# Receiving Error When Attempting to Change Value of Header Tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to change the value of a header tag to a localStorage key, but every time I reload my webpage I receive:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

What I tried:

1. Checking if the script is included after "userName" header tag.
2. Not building the page with Browserify
3. changing the value I was assigning the header tag to a regular string, giving the same result.

relevant code:

UData.js

```
const ud = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UD'));
const user = ud.username;
const pfp = ud.pfp;
const dob = ud.dob;
const lers = ud.lers;
const ling = ud.ling;
const fnds = ud.fnds;
const req = ud.req;
const bck = ud.bck;
const cnl = ud.cnl;
document.getElementById(userName).value = user;
//document.getElementById(lingNum).value = ling;
//document.getElementById(lersNum).value = lers;
console.log(ud);
console.log(user);
```

profile.html (sequential order)

```
<h4 class ="userName" name="userName" id="userName">xjohnx</h4>
```

...

```
<script src="js/UData.js"></script>
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong, some insight will mean the world to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need literal `'userName'` and not a variable `userName`.

```
document.getElementById('userName').value = user;
```

`document.getElementById(userName)` returns null in your example, which means there is no HTML element with such ID.

Edit: `value` attribute is not valid for `h4` tag. There are plenty of JQuery functions that allow you to change content of the element like `.text()` or `.html()`. Use one that better addresses your needs.

Comment: Okay so it's not giving me the error anymore which is a good sign, but it's also not making the changes to my front end. when I console.log variable user that derived from localStorage it indeed prints. I am confused.

Comment: I used innerHtml and it worked. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage.setItem('test', 1);
alert( localStorage.getItem('test') );
The main features of localStorage are:
Shared between all tabs and windows from the same origin.
The data does not expire. It remains after the browser restart